# Printing an values from a session array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, session, printing

I'm trying to print a list of values that I've stored in a session-variable array, and all I'm getting is that 'Headers already sent...' error. On the error page I can see the array working, but obviously it won't proceed from there. The line the error mentions is this:

```
$uploadedfiles = print_r($_SESSION['uploadedfiles']);
```

The array is declared and values are added to it with this:

```
array_push($_SESSION['uploadedfiles'], $file_name);
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks kindly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`print_r()` will automatically print to the screen. You need to set the second parameter to `true` to actually capture it in a variable.

```
$uploadedfiles = print_r($_SESSION['uploadedfiles'], true);
```

Comment: Specifically, any output to the browser will set the headers, so if you have `header()` called after that, you'll get that error.